After using the latest vscode version, the recently accessed path names on my remote server are not showing up completely
image1
After using the latest vscode version, the recently accessed path names on my remote server are not showing up completely.
Because I have several branches of code, the absolute paths are not the same
For example, there are paths such as "/data/code1/src" and "/data/code2/src", but in the new version, only "src" is displayed here, which makes me confused, I need to hover over the short path to show the full path. In previous versions, the full path is shown here.
I switched my vscode from the old version to the latest version 1.91.
In older versions, "/data/code1/src" or "/data/code2/src" should be displayed here, but in newer versions, it is displayed as "src".
